# Is a symmetric diagonal matrix in which every entry is non-negative positive semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a symmetric diagonal matrix in which $(A)_{ii} \geq 0$. Should one conclude that this matrix is positive semidefinite?

Comment: Yes, because the determinants are $\ge 0$ (Hurwitz criterion).

Comment: By the way, symmetric information is not required because every diagonal matrix is symmetric.

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in my example so I deleted it. Okay, I got your point. What you want to mean is that all the leading principal minors are non-negative. Right??

Comment: @Rajada right. I saw that the name in english is rather Sylvester's criterion (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion)).

Comment: Yes, I know about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, because- $x^TAx=\sum_{i=1}^{n}A_{ii}x_i^2\geq0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R^n}-{\theta_n}$.

Comment: Excellent @Rajada, I am so impressed

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation. @PatrickChidzalo